# Retrieving pdf file google cloud app engine php not working

Tags: php, google-app-engine, pdf, google-cloud-platform

[Error while pdf file fetching from google cloud app engine php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnI0n.png)

Dears, I am trying to view a pdf file on google cloud app engine hosting but my code is not working on google cloud while the same code is working on Hostgator. Following is the error.

PDF.js v1.8.177 (build: d6dfc26d)
Message: Unexpected server response (500) while retrieving PDF "https://cartah-167122.appspot.com/uploads/T2kTLH3UzH.pdf".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "***but my code is not working***" - Which code?

Comment: there is an error in line 1: `<?php` is unexpected

Comment: @PedroLobito here in src you will find my pdf path which is in 'q'. The same script is working in Hostgate but not in Google cloud plateform <iframe id="bookFrame" allowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen style="margin-top: 0; height: 650px; margin-bottom: 0; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" width="100%" height="300" src="<?php echo BASE_URL;?>/book/iframe.php?q=<?php echo $_REQUEST['q']; ?>"></iframe>